# How to bundle and reference a js file from node_modules using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Using BroadwayJS to play a video stream, I import the Player... and the Player object requires that I point to a Decoder file.

A comment in the Decoder file says

> The reason why this is all packed into one file is that this file can
>   also function as worker.
>         you can integrate the file into your build system and provide the original file to be loaded into a worker.

How can I webpack magic the decoder file from node_modules/BroadwayJS/Player/Decoder.js to the bundle and point to it from my file like "workerFile: /build/Decoder.js"?

Here's where I've been playing with webpack and webpackdevserver 
https://github.com/bobtista/broadway-reactjs

If I don't include the workerfile, I get an error that Player is trying to use new Decoder, and Decoder isn't a constructor... can I import the Decoder another way?

Comment: You can use `webpack.ProvidePlugin()` for that : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Using webpack config, you can add two entry points and then output them as separate files. Then from the code, just point to the file you need.

Something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index.js'],
        decoder: ['broadwayjs/Player/Decoder']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'assets'),
        filename: '[name]ReactBundle.js'
    }
}
```

Then run webpack in the terminal to generate the two files
Then go to the dist folder in another terminal window and run a simple http server with python or something (I think webpack dev server should also work, but I haven't had any luck getting the config right. Would love help here!)